# How to set the position

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

http://www.kampyle.com/ in this url when you scroll one picture always moves. I want to know this process name. How can they do it? After clicking this picture it's vanished and never appears even on refreshing the page. How do they get information that I clicked this picture? It will be helpful for me if someone gives me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They just set the anchor that contains the image to:

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```

It's called absolute positioning.

As for only showing it once, that can be handled with a cookie or with a session variable.

Comment: thanks for reply.There are some site after enter one wigged active,with out registration u can not see the page,wigged contain a registration form,when user scroll it's move how to do it

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the feedback button that remains on the bottom right corner, here is the CSS you need:

```
.button{
    z-index: 9999999;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

With this code you can have a fixed image on the bottom right corner:

```
<img src="feedback-button.gif" class="button" alt="Feedback button" />
```

BUt I don't see how the button is vanishing. I am quite sure that they have done it using a cookie or a session varibale which will pervent the button to appear on the next load of the page.

Comment: thanks for reply.There are some site after enter one wigged active,with out registration u can not see the page,wigged contain a registration form,when user scroll it's move how to do it.